# comparison of each line in two file

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a task to compare lines in two files.. values stores in files as string. I am new to Java so please forgive if there is some silly mistake :) 
file1 contains

```
1044510=>40000
2478436011=>10000
2478442011=>3500
2498736011=>3000
2498737011=>550
2478443011=>330
2478444011=>1,550
```

File two contains

```
1044510=>30,097
2478436011=>9,155
2478442011=>2,930
2498736011=>2,472
2498737011=>548
2478443011=>313
2478444011=>1,550
```

I want to take line one from first file and second file and check if value of line1 from first file is greater than second file or not. `(40000>30,097)` or not. Dont want to take values before "=>".
I have done a sample code but i am getting error while running.

```
private static void readfiles() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bfFirst = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(first_list));
    BufferedReader bfSecond = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(second_list));

    int index = 0;
    while (true) {

        String partOne = bfFirst.readLine();
        String partTwo = bfSecond.readLine();
        String firstValue=null;
        String secondValue=null;
        int firstValueInt;
        int secondValueInt;

        if (partOne == null || partTwo == null)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(partOne + "-----\t-----" + partTwo);
            firstValue=partOne.split("=>")[1];
            secondValue=partTwo.split("=>")[1];
            System.out.println("first valueee"+firstValue);
            System.out.println("second value"+secondValue);
            firstValueInt=Integer.parseInt(firstValue);
            secondValueInt=Integer.parseInt(secondValue);

            if(secondValueInt>firstValueInt)
            {
               System.out.println("greater");
            }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("lesser");
        }
      }

    }
}
```

}

This is the exception i get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30,097"
   at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
   at com.bq.pricefinder.flipkart.findProductDifferenceFromFiles.readfiles(findProductDifferenceFromFiles.java:45)
   at com.bq.pricefinder.flipkart.findProductDifferenceFromFiles.main(findProductDifferenceFromFiles.java:18)
```

Comment: The value is not int as it has floating point so you cannot parse it as int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can get integer only by adding this lines

`firstValue = firstValue.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
secondValue = secondValue.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");`

then convert it to integer

Comment: Same issue as with @blackSmith's solution.

Comment: @sarath While this gives you the right result, it is hacking and only confuses other people looking at your code. You should never do something like that, it is a bad practice.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that you are parsing decimal value as integer.

The exception

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "30,097"
```

is clear which says that decimal value `30,097` in an invalid format for an integer.

Use float instead of int, and then compare. Also, sometimes it depends on the locale what decimal symbol is used, it can be `,` for one country and `.` for another. Read also [THIS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html).

Answer (score 1):

`Integer.parseInt` can't work on strings containing non-digits. That's the cause of the `NumberFormatException`. Use it like this :

```
firstValueInt=Integer.parseInt(firstValue.replaceAll(",",""));
secondValueInt=Integer.parseInt(secondValue.replaceAll(",",""));
```

Comment: That doesn't make sense, note that "1,550" would be greater than "550" and that is obviously incorrect. OP should rather convert the values to double.

Comment: OP is asking about `NumberFormatException` only. The numbers in his files may be in different units, he didn't made it clear !

Comment: You are telling the OP how to get rid of the exception, however making the code function not as desired.

Comment: @pikausp : If someone needs algorithm to compare two numbers, I will certainly decline. And there is no info about the context of the problem.

Comment: thank you everyone for comments and this works well :) problem has been solved\